# How to execute a bat file with Chinese character, when the system is in Japanese Locale?

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, encoding, character-encoding

The windows system locale is Japanese and i was trying to execute the bat file which has the following command.

```
"C:\mysql\bin\mysql" --user=root --password=fddf! --host=127.0.0.1 --default-character-set=utf8 < E:\data\大村箕島\test.sql
```

But it fails and i can see those Chinese characters got converted into some-other character. But if i copy the command and paste it in the cmd, it gets executed properly.

I tried changing the code page to utf8(65001). But still it fails.
Later when i changed the system locale to Chinese and code page to 65001, the batch file started executing properly.

Can you please suggest me a way to execute that batch file keeping the system locale as Japanese itself(independent to system locale)?.